# How to do string(mixed numbers and letters) comparisons

Tags: bash, math

I'm trying to compare switch models(example: 2620-48-PWR, 2848, 5308xl, 5412zl) so I can run specific tests for specific models.  When I run the script I am getting the error:

tstVOIPConfigTest.bsh: line 207: 5412zl: arithmetic syntax error

However this page: (http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml) indicates that "Bash simply ignores any strings that don't contain numeric values and **generates an error for anything that contains both numbers and other characters**:"

Example Code:

```
if [[ $switchModel -eq "2810-48G" ]]; then
   echo "2810-48g Series Switch detected - verifying if qos-passthrough-mode is enabled" >> $errFile
   test "qos-passthrough-mode typical" "qos-passthrough-mode typical set" "qos-passthrough-mode typical not set"             
fi
```

Since my script is written in bash, my question is how can I accomplish what I need to do when bash inherently (as I understand it) does not do what I need it to?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: What precisely do you want?  Should 2810-48G evaluate as equal to 2810, or as equal to 48, or both, or neither, or what?

Comment: You're reading about arithmetic comparisons -  check out http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html - the "string comparison" section.

Comment: A 2810-48G should be different than a 2810-24G which is still difference than a 2810-48G-PWR.

Comment: @Robert Good.  In other words, you want to do a pure string comparison.  In that case, Glenn Jackman has the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `=` operator for string comparison.
`-eq` is strictly for numeric comparison

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Be aware that in `[[`, the `=` operator is not string equality: it is a **pattern matching** operator, so be cautious to  quote the right-hand value appropriately.

Comment: @F.Hauri, ugh, I feel nauseous! :) Why do you use the undocumented `$[]` instead of `$(())`?

Comment: @glennjackman bad habit! (and shorter;) I will try to wipe this bad habit anyway! Also `[ $((64#${switchModel//[ *+\/-]/_})) -eq $((64#2810_48G)) ]` will work, until `[ ${#switchModel} -gt $((64#${switchModel:0:1}>15?10:11)) ]` !! ... Sorry  for nausea ;-)